# Given two certificates, how can I verify that one was signed with the other's private key?

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have two `X509Certificate2`s. Call them `toCheck` and `checkWith`.

How can I check that `toCheck` was signed by the private key of `checkWith`?

Basically, I want the C# equivalent of Java's

```
toCheck.verify(checkWith.getPublicKey());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the value of that would be.  What if the certificate used to sign (checkWith) was revoked?  It sounds like you'd have a false sense of validation.

If you want to *validate* a certificate, you can use the [X509Certificate2.Verify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify.aspx) method

Comment: The value is in confirming that toCheck was signed by checkWith. In other words, in addition to the ordinary validations (cert is legit, dates are legit, signer not revoked, etc.), I also want to know that checkWith signed it.

Comment: Verify verifies that the cert was signed by a valid cert...  Simply checking that a cert is signed by another doesn't mean the signing cert is valid...  Verify verifies the entire chain of certs.

Comment: I understand that. But checking that a cert is "signed by a valid cert" is insufficient for my purposes. I want to know that it was signed by THIS valid cert.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the signature is not available. While you could calculate a signature from the results of GetRawCertData, there's nothing to compare it to.  The recommended method to verify a cert is to use the X509Chain.  If you created the cert from DER data, you could manually extract the signature, calculate a signature with the other cert and compare...